# Spring MVC REST mapping returning error 404 in postman

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on spring REST (Study Only) and I am stuck on following example where the result is supposed to be `200`, getting `404` as I have following code

Product.java

```
public class Product {
    protected String productId;
    protected String name;
    protected BigDecimal unitPrice;
    protected String description;
    protected String manufacturer;
    protected String category;
    protected long unitsInStock;
    protected long unitsInOrder;
    protected boolean discontinued;
    protected String condition;
```

cartItem.java

```
public class CartItem {

    protected Product product;
    protected int quantity;
    protected BigDecimal totalPrice;

    public CartItem() {
    }

    public CartItem(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = 1;
        this.totalPrice = product.getUnitPrice();
    }
```

cart.java

```
public class Cart {

    protected String cartId;
    protected Map<String, CartItem> cartItems;
    protected BigDecimal grandTotal;

    public Cart() {
        cartItems = new HashMap<>();
        grandTotal = new BigDecimal(0);
    }
```

cartController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public class CartRestController {

    @Autowired
    protected CartService cartService;

    @Autowired
    protected ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Cart create(@RequestBody Cart cart) {
        return cartService.create(cart);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        return cartService.read(cartId);
    }
```

and this is my json

```
{
    "cartId": "1234",
    "cartItems": {
        "P1234": {
            "product": {
                "productId": "P1234",
                "name": "iPhone 5s",
                "unitPrice": 500,
                "description": "Apple iPhone 5s smartphone with 4.00-inch 640 x1136 display and 8 - megapixel rear camera ",
                "manufacturer": "Apple",
                "category": "Smart Phone",
                "unitsInStock": 1000,
                "unitsInOrder": 0,
                "discontinued": false,
                "condition": "NEW"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 500
        }
    },
    "grandTotal": 500
}
```

Edit : 
Spring configuration file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.local.domain" />

    <mvc:resources location="/resource/" mapping="/resource/**" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="contentType" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="message" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="contentNegotiationViewResolver" -->
<!--        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean"> -->
<!--        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" /> -->
<!--        <property name="ignoreUnknownPathExtensions" value="true" /> -->
<!--        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" /> -->
<!--        <property name="useJaf" value="true" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

<!--    <mvc:view-resolvers> -->
<!--        <mvc:content-negotiation> -->
<!--            <mvc:default-views> -->
<!--                <bean -->
<!--                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" /> -->
<!--                <bean -->
<!--                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MappingJackson2XmlView" /> -->
<!--            </mvc:default-views> -->
<!--        </mvc:content-negotiation> -->
<!--    </mvc:view-resolvers> -->

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/springDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

after processing this request I am getting error `404` please help me to solve this, any help is appreciated. If you need anything more to know please let me know.

Comment: Can you post your Spring config? What's the complete URL you are hitting? Finally, if you are using Spring 4 you can use `@RestController` (at class level) and delete the `@ResponseBody` ones.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I made the edit please check

Comment: Nothing interesting there...what about the `web.xml`?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I added web.xml, please take a look

Comment: Can you try with `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`, for testing initially? Then change your URL accordingly to include, for instance: `http://localhost:8080/api/cart/cart-uuid` (notice you might also to specify the app's context before `/api/..`)

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I'm still getiing error 404

Comment: what is the url you are trying to invoke?

Comment: @kuhajeyan this is being used to post json data through postman `http://localhost:8080/cart/rest/`

Comment: @user7036414 your url doesn't seem to have app context. The url should be `http://localhost:8080/context/cart/rest/`

Answer (score 1):

Small thought(even though I haven't test this yet),  as if it is, method annotations they will be interpreted as relative URLs (relative to the class-level URL). So two things, you can try out and check.

1) Remove the class level mapping and place absolute url at the method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

2)Remove the root slash at the method level as below and keep the class level mapping as it is.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```